# Casperjs switch MainFrame to a new tab

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using casperjs to navigate a site, but I'm having trouble with the login process:

In the site, when you login, the browser is switched to a new tab and the login form is reset back to blank, I'm seeing this new tab with the data I need being requested in the navigation debug, like this:

```
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=www.thesite.com, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
```

I've noticed the isMainFrame = false and I've tried to switch the frame with some methods like switchToChildFrame, casper.withFrame() or casper.withPopup(), but I've failed.

Is there any way that I can retrieve and interact with the content of that request?

My code so far:

```
casper.start('www.thesite.com', function() {
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');
this.wait(2000);
casper.withFrame('centro', function() {
    this.fillSelectors('form[name="teclado"]', {
        'input[name="IdGroup"]': 'AAA',
        'input[name="IdUser"]': 'BBB',
        'input[name="password"]': 'CCC'
    }, false);
    //this capture retrieves the form filled with my data
    this.capture('../../../1.png');
    this.click("a[onclick='enviar();return true;']");
    });
});
casper.withFrame( 0, function(){
    //2.png is getting the form with blank fields
    this.capture('../../../2.png');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my issue

The problem was that I wrote the withPopup code badly

I wrote the regex to match the popup url too strict by putting most of the url I expected:

```
casper.withPopup(/Estatico\/BEComponentesGeneralesAccesoSEI\/Html\/login.htm/, function() {
```

This works OK for me:

```
casper.withPopup(/true$/, function() {
    this.capture('../../../2.png');
});
```